# Can we limit the visibility GUI element in Azure ARM template based on location?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

i want to display a Azure GUI element in solution offer only if the deployment is being done in certain region. I know there is a "visible" field for createUIdefinition elements. But Can i use location function with it.

I tried below, it seems to not work though. what am i missing:

```
{
        "name": "MyDropdown",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.DropDown",
        "label": "Only show in EastUS",
        "defaultValue": "blah",
        "toolTip": "select from below",
        "constraints": {
          "allowedValues": [
            {
              "label": "yes",
              "value": "yes"
            },
            {
              "label": "no",
              "value": "no"
            },

          ]
        },
        "visible": "[ equals(location(), 'eastus') ]"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like above example not working for createUIdefinition's basics section. Though , it works for steps section.